# How to select from mysql with more OR match

Tags: php, sql

say we have 10 columns ,

```
col1,col2 ... col10;
```

how to select a row `where col1 = "some" OR col2= "some" OR col3= "somethingelse" ... OR col10 = "who knows";` , with highest OR matching ?

row1 matches in `col1,col2,col3,col4`;

row2 matches in `col1,col4`;

want to select that `row1`,

Comment: What does `highest OR matching` means?

Comment: `OR` is not exclusive. Are you thinking of `XOR`, op?

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a search by a wildcard column. (Meaning all columns that are col*).

This can't be don't purely by MySQL AFAIK. 
You can fetch the matching columns the following way and then build a query using php.

```sql
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM information_schema.`COLUMNS` C
WHERE table_name = 'yourTable' AND COLUMN_NAME LIKE 'col%'
```

Use the matching columns to build the field list in PHP (aka implode the fields into 'col1'='x' OR 'col2' = 'x' etc.

Hope this helps,
Shai.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do would be something like this:

```
SELECT col1, col2, col3
FROM tblName 
ORDER BY ( IF(col1="some",1,0)
          +IF(col2="some",1,0)
          +IF(col3="somethingelse",1,0)...
          +IF(coln="who knows",1,0) )
Desc
```

doing it this way would make the row with most matches be at the top of the list, you can add Limit 1 statement at the end to show only the row with most matches.

Comment: i was thinking this way also , wanted to find other ways,thanks, i think i will do this way